# RobotFramework: Purpose and best practice for the resource- and library-folders

Tags: robotframework

I ponder on purpose and best practice for the Resource- and Library-folders usage in RobotFramework.

Below I have formulated some statements which serves to illustrate my questions. (Abbreviations used: KW = KeyWord, RF = RobotFramework, TS = TestSuite).

Statements/Questions:

Every KW, that is designed to be shared among TS, and written in RF-syntax, should be put inside a .resource-file in the Resource-folder?

Every KW written in Python should be put (as a method inside a .py-file) in the Library-folder?

I.e. the distinction-line between the Resource- and Library-folder is drawn based on syntax used when writing the KW (RF-KW go into Resource-folder and Python-KW go into Libraries-folder).

Or, should the distinction-line rather be drawn upon closeness to the test-rig and system under test. (i.e. High- or Low-level keywords. Where Low-level Keywords are said to be interact with the system under test). And hence you could place python KW (methods) in the Resource-folder?

Answer (score 0):

My take - Yes on everything, even on the last paragraph with the "Or,". Everything up until it were questions on the on the content/syntax of a file. And if your python (library) file has KW-s that make contextual sense to be in a folder with other similar RF (resource) files - place it there.

Remember two things: for Robotframework the distinction between `Resource` and `Library` is mainly what syntax it is expecting & how to import the target's resources. It doesn't enforce any rigid expectations on its purpose.
E.g. nothing stops you of having a high-level keyword developed in python like

```
def login_with_user_and_do_complex_compund_action(user, pass, other_arg)
```

, nor to create a relatively low-level KW written in Robotframework syntax:

```
Keyword For Complex Math That Should Better Be In Python
    [Arguments]   ${complex_number}   ${transformer_functuon}    ${other_arg}
```

The other thing is Robotframework is the tool(-set) with which you construct *your* automated testing framework for the SUT. By *your* framework I mean the structure & organization of suites and tests, their interconnections and hierarchy, and - the "helpers" for their operations - the before-mentioned resource (RF) and library (py) files.
As long as this framework is logically sound, has established conventions and is easy to grasp & follow, you can have any structure you find suiting you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I believe we will go for placing all files, containing KW's, inside the Resource-folder, no matter if the file is written in py or in rf (as I believe you suggested).

Comment: What I did suggest is: if the _logical_ layout of the functions in the file suggest they should be together, then placing them _physically_ in the same directory should be more than ok. Go with that :)